# xampp - python 3.7 - mysql error 1146 table not found

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-error-1146

**File: init.py**

```py
import sys
import time
import importlib

create_database = importlib.import_module("create-database")
from settings import *

create_database.import_tables_structure()
time.sleep(2)

import_settings()
time.sleep(2)
```

**File: create-database.py**

```py
import mysql.connector
import sys
import os
import traceback

def import_tables_structure():
    try:
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',host='localhost')
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        sql_file = open("papinhio-player.sql","r",encoding="utf-8").read()
        cursor.execute(sql_file,multi=True)
        cnx.commit()
        cursor.close()
        cnx.close() 
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = traceback.format_exc()
        print(error_message)

    #make folders
    try:
        os.mkdir(os.path.abspath("C:\\Users\\chris\\My Projects\\papinhio-player\\disket-box\\reports\\history-report"))
        os.mkdir(os.path.abspath("C:\\Users\\chris\\My Projects\\papinhio-player\\disket-box\\reports\\listeners-statistics-report"))
        os.mkdir(os.path.abspath("C:\\Users\\chris\\My Projects\\papinhio-player\\disket-box\\reports\\schedule-transmition-report"))
        os.mkdir(os.path.abspath("C:\\Users\\chris\\My Projects\\papinhio-player\\disket-box\\reports\\week-report"))

        os.mkdir(os.path.abspath("C:\\Users\\chris\\My Projects\\papinhio-player\\disket-box\\records\\ip-calls"))
    except:
        pass
        
#import_tables_structure()
```

**File: papinhio-player.sql**

```sql
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.1.1deb5ubuntu1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Aug 02, 2022 at 07:57 PM
-- Server version: 10.6.7-MariaDB-2ubuntu1.1
-- PHP Version: 8.1.2

SET SQL_MODE = "";
START TRANSACTION;

--
-- Database: `papinhio-player`
--

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `papinhio-player`;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `papinhio-player` COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- Table: settings
-- Used for saving program settings
-- such as auto_dj value (0,1)
-- Easy table (only 3 columns)

CREATE TABLE `papinhio-player`.`settings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `setting` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Indexes for table `settings`
--
ALTER TABLE `papinhio-player`.`settings`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `setting` (`setting`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `settings`
--
ALTER TABLE `papinhio-player`.`settings`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--
COMMIT;
```

**File: settings.py**

```py
import os
import sys

import mysql.connector

def import_settings():

    system_sound_volume = 50

    #default_font = "Times New Roman"
    default_font = "Calibri"
    default_font_size = 18
    default_font_color = "#000000"
    default_background_color = "#F1F1F1"
    default_buttons_background = "#F5F5F5"
    default_buttons_font_color = "#000000"
    #default_style = "WindowsVista"
    default_style = "Fusion"
    #default_custome_theme = "light_blue.xml"
    default_custome_theme = ""

    sql = """ INSERT INTO `settings` (`keyword`, `current_value`) VALUES ( ?, ?) """
    settings = []

    settings.append(("input_device_sound_volume",100))
    settings.append(("input_device_normalize",0))
    settings.append(("input_device_pan",0))
    settings.append(("input_device_low_frequency",20))
    settings.append(("input_device_high_frequency",20000))
    
    settings.append(("general_deck_sound_volume",50))
    settings.append(("general_deck_normalize",0))
    settings.append(("general_deck_pan",0))
    settings.append(("general_deck_low_frequency",20))
    settings.append(("general_deck_high_frequency",20000))
    
    settings.append(("player_list_display","Προβολή λίστας"))
    
    
    settings.append(("deck_1_relative_type",""))
    settings.append(("deck_1_relative_number",0))
    settings.append(("deck_1_current_duration_milliseconds",0))
    settings.append(("deck_1_repeats",0))
    settings.append(("deck_1_status",0))
    settings.append(("deck_1_total_time_milliseconds",0))

    settings.append(("deck_2_relative_type",""))
    settings.append(("deck_2_relative_number",0))
    settings.append(("deck_2_current_duration_milliseconds",0))
    settings.append(("deck_2_repeats",0))
    settings.append(("deck_2_status",0))
    settings.append(("deck_2_total_time_milliseconds",0))
    
    settings.append(("music_clip_deck_relative_type",""))    
    settings.append(("music_clip_deck_relative_number",0))    
    settings.append(("music_clip_deck_current_duration_milliseconds",0))       
    settings.append(("music_clip_deck_repeats",0))   
    settings.append(("music_clip_deck_status",0))
    settings.append(("music_clip_deck_total_time_milliseconds",0))
    
    
    settings.append(("default_font",default_font))
    settings.append(("default_font_size",default_font_size))
    settings.append(("default_font_color",default_font_color))
    settings.append(("default_background_color",default_background_color))
    settings.append(("default_button_background",default_buttons_background))
    settings.append(("default_button_font_color",default_buttons_font_color))
    settings.append(("default_style",default_style))
    settings.append(("default_custome_theme",default_custome_theme))
    
    settings.append(("player_field_change_position","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_play","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_title","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_last_play","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_next_play","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_image","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_prepare","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_play_now","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_remove","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_duration","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_artist","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_album","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_author","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_composer","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_year","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_description","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_from","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_rating","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_volume","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_normalize","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_pan","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_frequencies","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_repeat","1"))
    settings.append(("player_field_open_file","1"))

    settings.append(("player_fade_in","0"))
    settings.append(("player_fade_out","0"))
    
    settings.append(("program_component_tool_bar","1"))
    settings.append(("program_component_time_lines","1"))
    settings.append(("program_component_general_deck","1"))
    settings.append(("program_component_deck_1","1"))
    settings.append(("program_component_deck_2","1"))
    settings.append(("program_component_music_clip_deck","1"))
    settings.append(("program_component_speackers_deck","1"))
    settings.append(("program_component_ip_calls","0"))
    settings.append(("program_component_player_list","1"))
    settings.append(("program_component_web_sites","1"))
    settings.append(("program_component_scheduled_transmitions","1"))
    
    settings.append(("repeat_player_list","1"))
    settings.append(("auto_dj","1"))
    settings.append(("current-working-directory",os.path.abspath(".")))

    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',host='localhost',database='papinhio-player')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SET GLOBAL sql_mode='';")
    cnx.commit()
    cursor.execute("USE `papinhio-player`;")
    cnx.commit()    
    for setting in settings:
        sql = "INSERT INTO `papinhio-player`.`settings` (`setting`,`value`) VALUES (%s, %s);"
        cursor.execute(sql,(str(setting[0]),str(setting[1])))
        cnx.commit()
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()
```

If i run init.py the output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chris\My Projects\papinhio-player\database\create-database.py",
 line 12, in import_tables_structure
    cnx.commit()
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 42
5, in commit
    self._cmysql.commit()
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Commands out of sync; you can't run this c
ommand now

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 53
8, in cmd_query
    query_attrs=self._query_attrs)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Table 'papinhio-player.settings' doesn't e
xist

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "init_2.py", line 10, in <module>
    import_settings()
  File "C:\Users\chris\My Projects\papinhio-player\database\settings.py", line 1
66, in import_settings
    cursor.execute(sql,(str(setting[0]),str(setting[1])))
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 271, i
n execute
    raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 54
1, in cmd_query
    sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1146 (42S02): Table 'papinhio-player.se
ttings' doesn't exist
```

the database and table structure are created, but no insertion to settings table.

Then if i run python settings.py the insertions are done.
What's the problem?
Note: I tried multi=True in multi-query but then there is no database build in phpmyadmin.

Comment: You have a START TRANSATION but no COMMIT TRANSACTION.

Comment: That's true. I miss copied the sql file. Question editted. Problem didn't resolved.

Comment: And if you have a COMMIT in the string, then you don't need to call `cnx.commit()`.

Answer (score 0):

**File: create-database.py**

```py
import mysql.connector
import sys
import os
import traceback
import re

def import_tables_structure():
    try:
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',host='localhost')
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        exec_sql_file(cursor, "papinhio-player.sql")
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = traceback.format_exc()
        print(error_message)

    #make folders
    try:
        os.mkdir(os.path.abspath("C:\\Users\\chris\\My Projects\\papinhio-player\\disket-box\\reports\\history-report"))
        os.mkdir(os.path.abspath("C:\\Users\\chris\\My Projects\\papinhio-player\\disket-box\\reports\\listeners-statistics-report"))
        os.mkdir(os.path.abspath("C:\\Users\\chris\\My Projects\\papinhio-player\\disket-box\\reports\\schedule-transmition-report"))
        os.mkdir(os.path.abspath("C:\\Users\\chris\\My Projects\\papinhio-player\\disket-box\\reports\\week-report"))

        os.mkdir(os.path.abspath("C:\\Users\\chris\\My Projects\\papinhio-player\\disket-box\\records\\ip-calls"))
    except:
        pass

def exec_sql_file(cursor, sql_file):
    statement = ""

    for line in open(sql_file,"r",encoding="utf-8"):
        if re.match(r'--', line):  # ignore sql comment lines
            continue
        if not re.search(r';$', line):  # keep appending lines that don't end in ';'
            statement = statement + line
        else:  # when you get a line ending in ';' then exec statement and reset for next statement
            statement = statement + line
            #print "\n\n[DEBUG] Executing SQL statement:\n%s" % (statement)
            try:
                cursor.execute(statement)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                #print "\n[WARN] MySQLError during execute statement \n\tArgs: '%s'" % (str(e.args))

            statement = ""

#import_tables_structure()
```

The problem may was that with one mysql execution there is no enough time to apply the changes in mysql.

In this answer i use a sql file parser to execution one single query at one execution.

Now the settings insertions are done with no mistake.